# ORACLE TO_CHAR ERROR

Tags: oracle, to-char

I heve a function (use Dbms_sql.Varchar2s) that part of it is below:

```
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) :=  ' Select ';
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) :=  '  TIP.ID_ITEM,';
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) :=  '  CPVW.ID_FAB,';
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) := '  TO_CHAR(CPVW.QTD, ''9999999'') as QTD';
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) :=  ' from ';
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) :=  '  CAD_PILAR_VW CPVW';
```

When I execute it everithing is OK but when I change  the line  from

```
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) := '  TO_CHAR(CPVW.QTD, ''9999999'') as QTD';
```

to

```
str_work(Nvl(str_work.Last, 0) + 1) := '  TO_CHAR(CPVW.QTD, ''99999.99'') as QTD';
```

I got error invalid number

A table have only 3 values to CPVW.QTD :  100,  200,  300 and the type is NUMBER

I try a lot of "9999999" combination  with comma, decimal point and all cases I receive the same error. INVALID NUMBER.

The function only works if the TO_CHAR is ''9999999''  without comma or decimal point.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show the exact line of code raising the exception.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with your to_char conversation? Maybe you're treating the converted QTD somewhere else and this raises an exception? Try to use: TO_CHAR(CPVW.QTD, ''99999D99'')

Comment: Why are you using `Dbms_sql.Varchar2s` rather than a big text variable?

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing. Your query does not seem to be dynamic. So, use a cursor or an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement with bind variables.